Last 3 bought items (BigQuery)
There is big table with details on customers, bought items and date of the transaction.
I need a result which contains the name of the client and the last 3 items that were bought in columns last_item, second_item and third_item.



customer
item
date




1aa
A
2023-02-02 10:02:00


1aa
B
2023-02-02 10:01:00


1aa
B
2023-02-02 10:00:00


1aa
A
2023-02-02 09:01:00


1aa
D
2023-02-02 09:00:00


1aa
C
2023-02-02 08:00:00


2aa
A
2023-02-02 10:02:00


2aa
D
2023-02-02 10:01:00


3aa
C
2023-02-02 10:00:00



The result should be the following:



customer
last_item
second_item
third_item




1aa
A
B
D


2aa
A
D



3aa
C





I use
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer,item ORDER BY date DESC) as item_ranking

And them use the results in CTE query with CASEs, but I believe there should be better and more clean way to do this.

How come you want D as 1aa's third_item? I'd expect B (from 2023-02-02 10:00:00).

You can GROUP BY a ROW_NUMBER() partition by customer query's result, and use case expressions to get last_item etc.
select customer,
       max(case when item_ranking = 1 then item end) as last_item,
       max(case when item_ranking = 2 then item end) as second_item,
       max(case when item_ranking = 3 then item end) as third_item
from
(
    select customer, item,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY date DESC) as item_ranking
    from tablename
) dt
where item_ranking <= 3
group by customer

returns
customer last_item second_item third_item
======== ========= =========== ==========
1aa      A         B           B
2aa      A         D           -
3aa      C         -           -

However, if you want distinct items for each customer, you can pre-aggregate:
select customer,
       max(case when item_ranking = 1 then item end) as last_item,
       max(case when item_ranking = 2 then item end) as second_item,
       max(case when item_ranking = 3 then item end) as third_item
from
(
    select customer, item,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY date DESC) as item_ranking
    from
    (
        select customer, item, max(date) date
        from tablename
        group by customer, item
    ) pg
) dt
where item_ranking <= 3
group by customer

which returns:
customer last_item second_item third_item
======== ========= =========== ==========
1aa      A         B           D
2aa      A         D           -
3aa      C         -           -


You need to use lag and lead functions.
For your case it would be like this:
SELECT 
 customer, 
 lag(item) over(partition by customer order by date) as last_item,
 lag(item, 2) over(partition by customer order by date) as second_item,
 lag(item, 3) over(partition by customer order by date) as third_item
FROM yourtable

I recommend you read this part of the doc.

Will return all 9 rows.

Consider below approach (BigQuery)
select * from (
  select customer, item, 
    row_number() over(partition by customer order by date desc) as pos
  from your_table
  qualify pos < 4
)
pivot (
  any_value(item) as item 
  for ['last', 'second', 'third'][offset(pos - 1)] in ('last', 'second', 'third')
)

if applied to sample data in your question - output is


In case, you want to exclude dups from result - use below approach
with dedup as (
  select customer, item, date
  from your_table
  qualify row_number() over(partition by customer, item order by date desc) = 1
)
select *
from (
  select  customer, ['last', 'second', 'third'][offset(offset)] as offset, item
  from (
    select customer, array_agg(item order by date desc limit 3) items
    from dedup
    group by customer
  ) t, unnest(items) as item with offset
)
pivot (any_value(item) as item for offset in ('last', 'second', 'third'))  

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

